# Ubuntu 20.04 - Unknown entry when using zfs list

Tags: 20.04, zfs

I currently have a raidz2 pool on my home server :
[image]

While doing some troubleshooting for slow performance on my array, I used the zfs list command, and noticed a lot of entry "under" my current pool :
[image]

I done a quick search to know what they are but I have found no answer. At first I thought they were snapshots, but from my understanding there would be a "@" with some nome, not those kind of GUID. Anyone can explain to me what they are, and what can I do to probably get ride of them? And could they be the reason of the sudden sinking of the performance of my pool, even after adding a SLOG and a L2ARC?

Also, I don't know why they all say that the MOUNTPOINT is legacy, since I'm using the "proper" way to mount my ZFS pool :

```
 $ zfs get mounted epicpool/storage
NAME              PROPERTY  VALUE    SOURCE
epicpool/storage  mounted   yes      -
```

Thanks to any explanation you can bring to my poor soul.

Comment: Hello. Please do not post pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone can explain to me what they are

These are filesystem *datasets*

> what can I do to probably get ride of them?

`zfs destroy <DATASET_NAME>` will destroy it. A shell loop will help you managing the quantity

> And could they be the reason of the sudden sinking of the performance of my pool, even after adding a SLOG and a L2ARC?

Dataset quantity cannot be the only explanation of lower performance.
ZFS fine tunning is not so obvious. *Adding* SLOG, L2ARC, *whatever*, is not the way you should take. You need to know more about what you are storing (file size, I/O frequency, I/O rate, data singularity, etc) before setting ZFS the proper way.

> Also, I don't know why they all say that the MOUNTPOINT is legacy, since I'm using the "proper" way to mount my ZFS pool

Legacy is the default inherited value

*edit*

If `epicpool/storage` is mounted on `/share/storage` children with `legacy` setting will be mounted on:

- `epicpool/storage/foo`: `/share/storage/foo`
- `epicpool/storage/bar`: `/share/storage/bar`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Actually I've done some basic tunning for ZFS (disabling compression and atime, change block size, etc) and was seeing little to no increase in my performance, so I added to that point my L2ARC (and later SLOG)....but i'm still bottlenecked but I can't seems to find what's the root cause. I already searched for some tools or procedure to help me but, do you have some suggestions?